# Tkinter canvas not shrinking more than contents

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

When I expand my window, the `Canvas` expands properly. However, when I shrink the window, the `Canvas` does not shrink back like I want it to. At the very least, I want to make absolutely sure that the controls at the bottom do not get cut off and that the scroll bar activates if the contents of the `Canvas` don't all fit on the screen.

The only solution I could think of was binding to the `<Configure>` event of the `Toplevel` and having the program manually preform all of the calculations to figure out exactly how big the canvas should be to fit all of the items, but the canvas refused to shrink to the size I assigned to it.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Here is an image of what I mean:
[image: Image of what I mean]

Here is the relevant code:

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

class ResultsWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    """
    Window that displays the results of the search.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, results, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__master = master
        self.__lg = ListsGroup(self, results)
        self.__controlsFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.__okButton = ttk.Button(self.__controlsFrame, text = 'Delete Selection')
        self.__cancelButton = ttk.Button(self.__controlsFrame, text = 'Cancel')

        self.__lg.pack(side = 'top', expand = True, fill = 'both')
        self.__controlsFrame.pack(side = 'bottom')
        self.__okButton.pack(side = 'left')
        self.__cancelButton.pack(side = 'right')


class ListsGroup(ttk.Frame): # TODO: Come up with a better name
    """
    The grouping thing that contains the results list.
    """
    def __init__(self, master, results, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__sb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
        self.__can = tk.Canvas(self, height = 0, yscrollcommand = self.__sb.set)
        self.__sb.configure(command = self.__can.yview)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.__can.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
        self.__sb.grid(column = 1, row = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
        self.__packable = []
        self.__entries = []
        for x in results:
            self.__entries.append(ResultEntry(self.__can, x))
            self.__entries[-1].pack(side = 'top', expand = False, fill = 'x')



class ResultEntry(ttk.Frame):
    """
    A single result group.
    """
    def __init__(self, master, group, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__listbox = tk.Listbox(self, selectmode = 'extended', height = len(group), borderwidth = 1)
        self.__statusbox = tk.Canvas(self, width = 20, height = 0, bg = 'yellow', borderwidth = 0)
        for x in group:
            self.__listbox.insert('end', x)
        self.__listbox.pack(side = 'left', expand = True, fill = 'both')
        self.__statusbox.pack(side = 'right', expand = False)
        self.__len = len(group)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.fix_size)

    def fix_size(self, event = None):
        """
        Function to fix the size of the canvas to the size of the tree view.
        """
        self.__statusbox.configure(height = self.winfo_height() - 4)
```

Here is the function I used to test it and that created the picture:

```py
def rtest():
    a = tk.Tk()
    b = ResultsWindow(a, [['1','2','3','4'], ['2', 'a'], ['h', '5']])
    a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you creating a canvas and a scrollbar, and then calling `pack` to place things in the canvas? You can't scroll things added to a canvas with `pack`. What's the point of using a canvas?

Comment: @Bryan Maybe leave that as an answer to the problem? I didn't know that. I used it because it was just the simplest way to make sure the items were all ordered how I wanted them to. I had no idea the geometry manager would be the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Since that was the answer, feel free to actually say that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my problem was that I was using the `Pack` geometry manager inside the canvas as opposed to the `Grid` geometry manager. Changing the geometry manager fixed all of my problems.

Thank you to @BryanOakley for pointing out that you can't scroll with the pack manager. I had absolutely no idea.